# is this a chip & signature amex?

Tags: credit-card, chip-card

[image: amex]

Well it looks like it has a chip in it so idk.

I ask because I'll be doing some international traveling soon and would like a [chip & signature amex](http://chipandsignature.americanexpress.com/).

Comment: Which country ?? That doesn't look like a chip for EU states.

Comment: Japan and the UK.

Comment: In that case your card will be swiped at terminals. In UK atleast most places have chip and pin, same in EU if I amn't wrong and this card mayn't work. So it will be swiped, I am not sure if it will go for contactless or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **not** a EU-kind chip-and-signature card. This is a RFID chip that allows waving the card at the cash register instead of swiping it, but it doesn't add any additional security and has no crypto component in it.

Comment: All these cards do is send the card's details when it's swiped. The details include card number, start date, end date, & name on the card.

Comment: @bob This is not always true. You're right that with some RFID cards, the swipe-equivalent data is exactly the same each time it is read. However,  with others the discretionary data in the right-hand portion of the track changes with each swipe. Imagine a simple integer swipe-read count being  incremented there. This provides a unique-per-swipe track equivalent, which allows authorizers never to authorize the same unique swipe more than once, thereby preventing repeat playbacks. It's pretty predictable though as cryptograms go in that I've only ever seen the auto-increment kind myself.